# How do I modify wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php to include extra row?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple theme in WordPress that I want to add an additional row to the header of the site above the logo and nav.

I understand that wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php needs to be edited however I am unable to work out what code to use to achieve this. The row would have right aligned in it our phone number. The website is www.gpoint.co.uk.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In function.php of your child theme add the following:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'add_phone_line');
function add_phone_line(){
  // Loading just before rendering the template
  $("header:first-child").prepend("<div class='phone'><p>Phone number: 1234567890</p></div>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This when placing it into the functions.php file causes a server 500 error. Any thoughts?